# Python - Matplotlib: plotting pivot table for hydrological year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working currently on some hydrological data, therefore I do some analysis with the pivot function. Thus the hydrological year does count from October to September I want to plot them that way. So, is there a way in matplotlib to change the sorting of the x-Axis in my plot?

My pivot function looks like this:

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(df_mb, index=df_mb.index.month, columns=df_mb.index.year, aggfunc='mean')

pv.MB

    2011        2012            2013
1   NaN         0.159587        0.119823
2   NaN         0.134704        0.129065
3   NaN         0.163604        0.156006
4   NaN         0.451304        0.260984
5   NaN         0.202280        0.286951
6   NaN         -0.656959       -0.266000
7   NaN         -1.000123       -1.284144
8   NaN         -1.477041       -0.694400
9   NaN         0.002894        -0.196538
10  0.186086    0.191084        0.307935
11  0.299759    0.451645        NaN
12  0.133154    0.048562        NaN
```

and pvovides me a plot like this:
[image: Pivot-plot]
<sub>(source: [exi.rocks](https://www.exi.rocks/static/MB-pivot-wrong-stackoverflow.png))</sub>

So, I want my plot's x-axis to start at 10 and end at 9. Has anybody a clue how to get there?

Comment: btw.: reindexing does not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define new columns like this:

```
df['col'] = np.where(df.index.month < 10, df.index.year, df.index.year + 1)
df['idx'] = np.where(df.index.month < 10, df.index.month+3, df.index.month-9)

df.pivot_table(index='idx',columns='col', values='val', aggfunc='mean')
```

gives, e.g:

```
col  2014  2015
idx            
1       8     7
2       8     3
3       6     6
4       2     4
5       8     3
6       7     7
7       2     6
8       1     1
9       5     3
10      4     5
11      4     8
12      5     4
```

Comment: thank you so much, this solved my "next problem" - getting correct labels - too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to reorder the dataframe, reset the index and use the column `'index'` generated by `reset_index()` (the reordered index) as new tick labels.

```
dd = pd.concat([df.loc[df.index[9:]], df.loc[df.index[:9]]]).reset_index()

ax = dd[dd.columns.drop('index')].plot()
ax.set_xticks(dd.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(dd['index'])
plt.xlabel("month")
plt.show()
```

You get this:

[image]